# Vista network connection red x and unknown server execution failed

Tags: networking, windows-vista

Windows Vista network connection icon has a red x in it and states, “Connection status: Unknown Server execution failed” on mouse hover, and the Network and Sharing center won’t open when I try.

I've tried rebooting, looked over ipconfig, checked event viewer, safe mode, and sfc /scannow. It's connected to Ethernet and same cable allows other laptop to get IP and browse network just fine.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log on as a local administrator and then run these commands one-by-one followed by a reboot in order from command prompt ***running as administrator***:

- `net localgroup "Administrators" "NT Authority\Local Service" /add`

Sign back on after the reboot and check to see if the issue goes away.  If it doesn't then try doing the same thing but with this account and then reboot and try again:

- `net localgroup Administrators localservice /add`

If neither of these work, you may want to try again in that same order per command but boot to safe mode and run while logged on as local administrator.

---

### Further Resources

- [Connection status unknown server execution failed" problem](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/connection-status-unknown-server-execution-failed/af9625cc-1a27-4271-9092-838588553ffc?auth=1)
- [NET.exe ACCOUNTS / NET USER / NET GROUP](https://ss64.com/nt/net-useradmin.html)